# retrieve number of CPU and RAM from AWS instance using AWS tool for powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to retrieve the number of CPU and RAM from aws instances using the below command.

```
$AwsInstances = (Get-Ec2Instance -Region $rg).Instances
```

however, i can't find any properties that store the information. 
can someone please help?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a CommandLet Get-EC2InstanceType which can help with your need. Below is a code sample that will give you all details about the given instance:

```
$instances = Get-EC2Instance -Select Reservations.Instances #obtain list of instance objects
$instances[0].GetType().fullname #confirm the object you are working with
Amazon.EC2.Model.Instance

$instances[0].InstanceType #attribute we want to focus

Value
-----
m5.large

Get-EC2InstanceType -InstanceType $instances[0].InstanceType |Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemoryInfo #memory

SizeInMiB
---------
8192

Get-EC2InstanceType -InstanceType $instances[0].InstanceType |Select-Object -ExpandProperty VCpuInfo #vcpu details

DefaultCores          : 1
DefaultThreadsPerCore : 2
DefaultVCpus          : 2
ValidCores            : {1}
ValidThreadsPerCore   : {1, 2}
```

You can also pull out every details for the given instance into json format and save it for your later use:

```
Get-EC2InstanceType -InstanceType $instances[0].InstanceType | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File C:\ProgramData\temp\temp.json #store given instance's 'type' details in a json file

Get-EC2Instance |foreach {$_.Instances | foreach {Get-EC2InstanceType -InstanceType $_.InstanceType}}
```

I hope this gets you started with testing and trying with the scenario that matches your use case.